# Fill tikz command

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a problem with the fill command in Tikz.

My problem is that the dashed area exceeds/or is shrinked in all directions. I want to have a dashed area filling exactly the area about the line.

Any help to adjust the filled area ? Thanks

[image]

The code is

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}


\begin{document}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw[gray!50, thin, step=0.5] (-1,-1) grid (5,4);
                \draw[very thick,->] (-1,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$x_1$};
                \draw[very thick,->] (0,-1) -- (0,5) node[above] {$x_2$};
                
                % absice des axes 
                \foreach \x in {-1,...,5} \draw (\x,0.05) -- (\x,-0.05) node[below] {\tiny\x};
                \foreach \y in {-2.5,...,4} \draw (-0.05,\y) -- (0.05,\y) node[right] {\tiny\y};
                
                %   \fill[blue!50!cyan,opacity=0.3] (8/3,1/3) -- (1,2) -- (13/3,11/3) -- cycle;
                
                \draw[name path=line1] (2,4) -- node[above right,sloped] {\tiny$2x_A+x_B\leq8$} (4.5,-1);   % desig une ligne
                \fill [blue!50!cyan, above ,opacity=0.3, domain=-1:2, variable=\x]
                (5,4)
                -- plot ({\x}, {8 -2* \x})
                --  (4.5,-1)
                --  (5,-1)
                -- cycle;
                
                
                \draw[name path=line2] (-1,3) -- node[above ,sloped] {\tiny$x_B\geq3$} (5,3);   % desig une ligne
                \fill [green!50!cyan, above ,opacity=0.3, domain=-1:2, variable=\x]
                (-1, 4)
                -- plot ({\x}, {3})
                -- (5, 4)
                -- cycle;
                
                
                \draw[name path=line3] (-1,4) -- node[below left,sloped] {\tiny$x_1+2x_B\leq7$} (5,1);   % design line  
                \fill [red!50!cyan, above ,opacity=0.3, variable=\x]
                (-1,4)
                -- plot ({\x}, {7/2 - (1/2)*\x})
                -- (5,4)
                -- cycle;
                
                
                \draw[name path=line3] (-1,0) -- node[above left,sloped] {\tiny$x_A\geq0$} (5,0);   % design line   
                \fill [red!50!cyan, above ,opacity=0.3, variable=\x]
                (-1,-1)
                -- plot ({\x}, {0})
                -- (5,-1)
                -- cycle;
                
                
                
                \draw[name path=line3] (0,-1) -- node[above left,sloped] {\tiny$x_B\geq0$} (0,4);   % design line   
                \fill [red!50!cyan, above ,opacity=0.3, variable=\x]
                (-1,-1)
                -- plot ({0}, {\x})
                -- (-1,4)
                -- cycle;
                
    \end{tikzpicture}

        
\end{document}
```

All suggestions are more than welcomed

Comment: Hello! What is your problem?

Comment: @Puck thanks. My problem is that the dashed area exceeds/or is shrinked in all directions. I want to have a dashed area filling exactly the area about the line.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Any help ?

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`

Comment: Please refer to this thread for the MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: @Zarko Thanks for your suggestions. I modifed the post.

Comment: @anis Thanks for your suggestions. I modifed the post.

Comment: Q: is your question specific to `beamer`? does it work on `article`?  if the answer is no to any of these, you  should make it work in `article` first then get it to beamer.

Comment: Also, there is a duplicate `\begin{tikzpicture}`

Comment: `\usetikzlibrary{intersections}` is also missing. This isn't a Minimal Working Example, yet. Thus,  we cannot help you.

Comment: @anis thank you very much for your feedback... I updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is realisation of your diagram. Know that there are many ways to achieve it with some being more efficient than others.

I am gonna plot only one area to explain how I did it:

[image: fill area]

I kept your grid and axis. I just gave x and y-axes name paths.

I used the [`intersections`](https://tikz.dev/tutorial#sec-2.16) tikz library which allows to compute intersections between named lines. For that, I needed to define a few lines. In the code below, you can see how I defined them. The most important part is

`\path [name intersections={of=line1 and line2, by=pt-of-intersection}] (1,0) -- (pt-of-intersection);`

### code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% The grid
\draw[gray!50, thin, step=0.5] (-1,-1) grid (5,4);
\draw[name path = axis-x, very thick,->] (-1,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$x_1$};
\draw[name path = axis-y, very thick,->] (0,-1) -- (0,5) node[above] {$x_2$};

% the axes' ticks
\foreach \x in {-1,...,5} \draw (\x,0.05) -- (\x,-0.05) node[below] {\tiny\x};
\foreach \y in {-2.5,...,4} \draw (-0.05,\y) -- (0.05,\y) node[right] {\tiny\y};


% draw the line and name it line1
\draw[name path=line1] (3,4) -- node[above right,sloped] {\tiny$2x_A+x_B\leq8$} (4.5,-1);
% draw define an asymptote at y=4 but don't draw it
\path [name path = asymptote] (-1,4)--(5,4);
% compute intersection of the two lines named asymptote and line1, the output is named y-cross
\path [name intersections={of=asymptote  and line1, by=y-cross}];
% compute intersection of the two lines named axis-x and line1, the output is named x-cross
\path [name intersections={of=axis-x and line1, by=x-cross}];
% fill the spaec between the 4 points
\fill [blue!50!cyan,opacity=0.3](y-cross) -- (x-cross)-- (5,0)-- (5,4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You should be able to do the other by yourself if you understand this one.
Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks @anis ! That perfect. But how to extand the dashed area for negative values of y (y<0).

Comment: `\fill [blue!50!cyan,opacity=0.3](y-cross) -- (x-cross)-- (5,0)-- (5,4);` this line says that tikz should fill the shape composed of these 4 nodes, `x-cross` is the intersection between `x-axis` and `line1`.  You could do this, `(y-cross) -- (5,-1)-- (5,4)` or even define a new at y=-1 and get the intersection of `line1` with it.

Comment: in other words you can use absolute positioning of nodes `(x,y)` or use `intersection` to compute the intersection of 2 lines.

Comment: Thanks for your help